# ERROR 1045 (28000):

Tags: mysql

Cuando intento acceder a `Mysql` en un `mac` con OSX Sierra y aparece como respuesta el siguiente error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES

Necesito ayuda para avanzar. Gracias

Comment: Verificar la clave de **Mysql** en tu cadena de Conexión ,puede que sea errónea

Comment: También puede ser problema del Host, si entras por dns 'localhost' no es lo mismo que 127.0.0.1, depende de como tengas configurado el server ( skip-name-resolve )

Comment: Ok. muchas gracias Joel, ahora ya pude acceder a mysql, efectivamente era la password.